# Azure DevOps - Deployment Pools On-premises agents behind a network firewall

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

This question relates to "Deployment Pool" member agents and not "Agent Pool" for builds (Microsoft still needs to work a bit to prevent the amount of confusion around the two. Its the same agent software, but that agent can be configured either to do builds of software OR just deploy artefacts to and run deployments)

Microsoft has a brief section on agents behind an on-prem firewall, but its a mixed message that doesn't clearly address just deployment pool agents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#communication

(In the above link its the section called "Communication to deploy to target servers")

In the graphic, in my mind, it should look more like the image I have adapted [and attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1THo.png)

I have a battle around approval from network security to allow the agent software on a deployment pool agent to connect up to Azure DevOps to allow release pipelines to be triggered to it and artefacts to be downloaded to them.

I have said back that I believe each server you want to deploy an artefact and list of deployment steps in that pipeline will need to have the agent software  installed AND have direct connectivity back to dev.azure.com via port 443

Am I correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not correct, you need 443 **outbound** connectivity to these domains:

For organizations using the *.visualstudio.com domain:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com 
https://{organization_name}.visualstudio.com
https://{organization_name}.vsrm.visualstudio.com
https://{organization_name}.pkgs.visualstudio.com
https://{organization_name}.vssps.visualstudio.com
```

For organizations using the dev.azure.com domain:

```
https://dev.azure.com
https://*.dev.azure.com
https://login.microsoftonline.com
https://management.core.windows.net
```

even if you want to deploy agents directly to the servers, its still outbound connectivity, not inbound. agent is polling Azure Devops, not vice versa.

Comment: I think my train of thought is that a deployment agent has to be installed on every server I want to deploy to, and that agent needs to connect outbound to those domains above. Otherwise deployment steps that use a single agent for that to reach out to agentless servers would be very "hacky" and require a lot of remote Powerhselling (as an example)

Comment: either way its **OUTBOUND** connectivity